# Constant 'weight' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am doing Angela Yu ios development bootcamp online, seems that some code is a bit outdated, stuck on this error, that I don't know how to fix.

```
 @IBAction func weightSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let weight = weightLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", sender.value)
        
        print(weight)
        
        weightLabel.text = "\(weight)kg"
```

I don't know what is data type (), also app works perfectly before I put weight in a constant. When I put it in a constant, it just prints ()kg on the weightLabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `let weight = ...` line contains two assignments which is not supported (it never was).

Probably you want this

```
@IBAction func weightSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let weight = String(format: "%.2f", sender.value)
   
    print(weight)
    
    weightLabel.text = "\(weight) kg"
}
```